# State of matter associated to family of quantum error correcting codes

Tags: surface-code

Is there a sense in which a family of $ [[n,1,d]] $ quantum error correcting codes, where $ d $ increases with $ n $, can always be associated to the ground state of some system?

The example I have in mind is the $ [[L^2,1,L]] $ surface code.